# Rejeição NFSe SP Assinatura dos dados XML Difere do Calculado SHA1 VB.net

Tags: xml, vb.net, sha1

Estou assinando a seguinte string: *339575410000100000000000120150413NI00000000000005000000000000002502917N207293716000260*

Usando o seguinte código:

```
' Obtem o certificado
        Dim CertificadoDig As X509Certificate2 = ObtemCertificado("")

        ' Converte os dados ASCII para Bytes
        Dim data() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(String_AssADC)

        Dim csp As RSACryptoServiceProvider = DirectCast(CertificadoDig.PrivateKey, RSACryptoServiceProvider)

        'Gerando Hash(array de bytes) utilizando SHA1
        Dim sha As New SHA1Managed()
        Dim hash() As Byte = sha.ComputeHash(data)

        'Assinando o HASH(array de bytes) utilizando RSA-SHA1
        Dim encrypted As Byte() = csp.SignHash(hash, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA1"))

        'Verifica se a Assinatura é Valida
        Dim isValid As Boolean = csp.VerifyData(data, "SHA1", encrypted)

        Return Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted)
```

Gostaria de saber se quando gero o Hash, ele já assina? Pois vi que isso pode acontecer, e se isso acontecer eu estarei assinando 2 vezes e acredito que aí deve estar o erro, o WebService da Prefeitura de São Paulo, retorna com a seguinte mensagem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
  <RetornoEnvioRPS xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.prefeitura.sp.gov.br/nfe">
  <Cabecalho Versao="1" xmlns="">
  <Sucesso>false</Sucesso> 
  </Cabecalho>
  <Erro xmlns="">
  <Codigo>1057</Codigo> 
  <Descricao>Rejeição: Assinatura difere do calculado.</Descricao> 
  </Erro>
  </RetornoEnvioRPS>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RESOLVIDO!!!

Felipe, conseguiu resolver o seu problema?

Enfim descobri o problema da assinatura (*1057-Rejeição: Assinatura difere do calculado*): CR e LF!

Graças a quebra de linha, meu XML era assinado de uma maneira e validado de outra no WebService da prefeitura, pois provavelmente lá ele considera apenas as Tags e valores, o que acaba gerando a divergência no cálculo da assinatura!

Quanto a assinatura interna, da TAG , eu montei a String e assinei com o código abaixo, e também ficou correta!

```
public string SignRPS(X509Certificate2 cert, String sAssinatura) 
{ 

//recebe o certificado e a string a ser assinada 
System.Text.ASCIIEncoding enc = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding(); 

RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(); 

//pega a chave privada do certificado digital 
rsa = cert. PrivateKey as RSACryptoServiceProvider; 

//cria o array de bytes e realiza a conversao da string em array de bytes 
byte[] sAssinaturaByte = enc.GetBytes(sAssinatura); 

RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter rsaf = new RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter(rsa); 
SHA1CryptoServiceProvider sha1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider(); 

//cria a variavel hash que armazena o resultado do sha1 
byte[] hash; 
hash = sha1.ComputeHash(sAssinaturaByte); 

//definimos o metodo a ser utilizado na criptografia e assinamos 
rsaf.SetHashAlgorithm("SHA1"); 
sAssinaturaByte = rsaf.CreateSignature(hash); 

//por fim fazemos a conversao do array de bytes para string 
string convertido; 
convertido = Convert.ToBase64String(sAssinaturaByte); 

return convertido; 
}
```

**OBS:** depois eu ajustei esse código a minha necessidade, pois já temos rotinas de assinatura no sistema de onde eu trabalho, e no fim o grande vilão era a forma que estava codificando a String em Array de Bytes: eu usava **UnicodeEncoding** e na verdade para Sampa deve ser **System.Text.ASCIIEncoding**

Answer (score 1):

Felipe, estou tendo exatamente o mesmo problema, mas depois de ler um pouco o manual da NFSe de São Paulo eu reparei que existem 2 retornos "parecidos":

1057-Rejeição: Assinatura difere do calculado *(que é este erro que voce descreveu acima, e o mesmo que ocorre comigo)*

1206-Assinatura Digital do RPS incorreta. *(erro referente a assinatura da tag )*

Em outros foruns, vi pessoas dizerem que quando esta assinatura interna esta incorreta, elas recebem a mensagem: "Assinatura Digital do RPS incorreta - String verificada (XXXXXX)", conforme post no GUJ: http://www.guj.com.br/25178-nfs-e-paulistana---problemas-na-assinatura-da-rps-tag-assinatura

Ou seja: creio que o problema não seja na assinatura interna do RPS, e sim, na assinatura do arquivo XML!

Answer (score -1):

Não necessáriamente, ele devolve o erro 1206 quando a string gerada está com algum problema, não deveria ser assim, o erro 1206 deveria voltar se houvesse algo referente a assinatura e não a formação da string, mas não é isso que acontece, no meu caso, obtenho erro 1206, quando tento enviar nota sem identificar o tomador, sem cpf ou cnpj, quando coloco o cpf já não obtenho erro algum, nada relativo a assinatura digital da RPS incorreta, mas é o que me retorna.